# How to set dynamic react class variable in flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a map that sets a ref of items. In this case, it's a `video`.

```js
const ref = this[`video-${index}-ref`];
```

How can I flow type this correctly? The number of indexes can be different.

Comment: What is the expected `correct` here?

Answer (score 1):

If all the types of

```
this[`video-${index}-ref`];
```

are similar and know (for example, they all are `VideoRefType`), it is possible to do the type casting, like the following:

```
const ref = ((this[`video-${index}-ref`]: any): VideoRefType);
```